# HTML Canvas making lines using mouseover event

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to write a code using HTML canvas that will create a line beginning where a mousemove event occurs.  The line has a defined direction and should continue extending until it is off the screen. The issue I am having is that every time I move the mouse a new line begins(this is good) but the previous line stops extending. I believe that the issue is because each new line is taking on a set of parameters with the same name as the previous line, however I am not certain that this is the issue, nor do I know how to fix it.

Here is a jsfiddle of my current code: https://jsfiddle.net/tdammon/bf8xdyzL/

I start be creating an object named mouse that takes an x and y parameter.  The `xbeg` and `ybeg` will be the starting coordinates for my lines.

```
let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height= window.innerHeight;

let c = canvas.getContext('2d');
let mouse ={
    x:undefined,
    y:undefined,
}

window.addEventListener("mousemove",function(event){
    mouse.x = event.x;
    mouse.y = event.y;
    xbeg = mouse.x;
    ybeg = mouse.y;
})
```

Next I create an animate function that continuously calls itself.  I create a new line object which will take the `xbeg` and `ybeg` parameters for beginning points and `xbeg+10` and `ybeg+10` as ending point.  The function then increments `xbeg` and `ybeg`.  I would like this function to create new lines that do not stop extending whenever the mouse is moved.

```
function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    new Line(xbeg,ybeg,xbeg+10,ybeg+10)

    c.beginPath();
    c.moveTo(xbeg,ybeg);

    c.lineTo(xbeg+10,ybeg+10);
    c.stroke();

    xbeg += 1;
    ybeg += 1;
}
```

Comment: If you want the lines to extend, you should run their `+= 1` in a loop until they reach the end of the canvas.

Comment: Won't this prevent new lines from being created while the loop is running?

Comment: You won't want to create a new line while the loop is running. Don't let `.beginPath()` take place, until after the loop is done. You can't draw two lines simultaneously, unless you use two canvases. Also, that would just make everything black really quick, unless you test the time between mousemoves.

Comment: @PHPglue I think we have different ideas about the final product here. If you follow the JS fiddle link I want to keep that same functionality only I don’t want the lines to stop moving when I move the mouse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've added to your code an array for all your lines: `let linesRy = [];`  and I've changed a bit your draw() function by adding `this.endx++; this.endy++;`

also I'm using your commented out `c.clearRect(0, 0, innerWidth, innerHeight);`since with every frame you redraw all the lines.
I hope this is what you need.

```js
let linesRy = [];
let canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

let c = canvas.getContext("2d");
let mouse = {
  x: undefined,
  y: undefined
};
let xbeg, ybeg;

window.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {
    mouse.x = event.x;
    mouse.y = event.y;
    xbeg = mouse.x;
    ybeg = mouse.y;
});

class Line {
  constructor(begx, begy, endx, endy, dx, dy, slope) {
    this.begx = begx;
    this.begy = begy;
    this.endx = endx;
    this.endy = endy;
    this.dx = endx - begx;
    this.dy = endy - begy;
    this.slope = dy / dx;
  }

  draw() {
    this.endx++;
    this.endy++;
    c.beginPath();
    c.moveTo(this.begx, this.begy);
    c.lineTo(this.endx, this.endy);
    c.stroke();
  }
}

//let xend = 420;
//let yend = 220;

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  c.clearRect(0, 0, innerWidth, innerHeight);

  linesRy.push(new Line(xbeg, ybeg, xbeg + 10, ybeg + 10, 10, 10, 1));

  linesRy.forEach(l => {
    l.draw();
  });
}

animate();
```

```css
canvas{border:1px solid;}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Answer (score -2):

the variable c is taken local variable

```js
function animate() {
 c = canvas.getContext('2d');
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    new Line(xbeg,ybeg,xbeg+10,ybeg+10)

    c.beginPath();
    c.moveTo(xbeg,ybeg);

    c.lineTo(xbeg+10,ybeg+10);
    c.stroke();

    xbeg += 1;
    ybeg += 1;
}
```